# Unable to install software through Ubuntu Sotware Centre on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: software-center, gparted, 9.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

I tried to install gparted through USC and an error showed up "installArchive()failed:". Trying to install any other software also gives the error. Any suggestions on how to remove the error or install by any other means?

Comment: is there any reason you still need to remain with that old version?

Comment: We are not allowed to upgrade to the newer version.

Comment: @Chinnu, you need to explain to the person who says you are not allowed to upgrade that it is a very bad idea to continue to run unsupported software that is no longer getting security fixes.